# Using NSURLSessionDataTask with Restkit

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

I am using Restkit 0.20 in our iOS application. I want to implement **ios 7 Background Transfer Service** for fetching the data using NSURLSessionDataTask.
Can anyone please let me know how to use NSURLSessionDataTask with Restkit with a simple example.

Thanks in advance, prodeveloper

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing there is an experimental branch looking at using URL sessions but no production support yet.

So, at the moment you would want to keep them apart. Use the session to download the data and then pass that data to a mapping operation.

Comment: Can you please give me a small example how to save the downloaded data (using session) to core data using restkit.

Comment: That isn't a small sample. You can find 2 tutorials online, 1 for the session download and one for using a mapping operation in RestKit.